# Authenticity check in a AJAX Post Jquery in Rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am playing around with AJAX in Rails 4 using a Jquery POST.  I know that all forms in Rails create an accompanying `authenticity_token` to prevent cross-site attacks etc.  But when I implemented the AJAX call below (off a basic scaffolded User), I did not include the token in the data object, but the same endpoint accepts this Jquery POST and updates the record.  Is this a security concern or is Rails handling this somewhere in the background?

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />

  <%= f.label :email %>:
  <%= f.text_field :email, id: 'email_field' %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<script>
    // when the #email_field changes
    var email_timeout;
    $("#email_field").keypress(function() {
        clearTimeout(email_timeout);
        email_timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
            $("#email_field").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%= user_path %>',
                data: { _method:'PUT', user: { email : $('#email_field').val() } },
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#email_field").removeAttr("disabled");
                    alert( "Data Saved" );
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    $("#email_field").removeAttr("disabled");
                    alert( "Error: Data not saved" );
                }
            });
        },2000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know there is no token?  Did you use Firebug or some other browser debug tool?  It should be there.

Comment: Using Chrome and Network tab > XHR: I can see the "Request Headers" which include tokens for `_myapp_session`, and `X-CSRF-Token`.  But I don't see the payload `email` or the `authenticity_token`.